# Simple GUI library for basic GLUT CAD application?

Tags: user-interface, widget, glut

I want to create a very simple CAD application written with GLUT library. I just need this to create simple dice editor application for computer graphics class, so an easy-to-use GUI library that supported GLUT is what I basically need for this project. I stumble upon GLUI, but it doesn't have widgets such as color chooser or file loader dialog. Is there a suitable GUI library for GLUT that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

There are gui libraries like Qt or FLKT, but they have their own main loop.
on windows you should call directly the native files dialogs GetOpenFileName() and GetSaveFileName(). If you want a cross platform solution and to exactly answer the question, yes there is "a suitable GUI library for GLUT that (you) can use": look for tiny file dialogs on sourceforge it even has a color chooser and has no main loop.

Answer (score -1):

*You want a simple GUI library yet you want it to have advanced features.*

### Open File Dialog

Depending on what OS you want it to be running on you can pop up the OS specific file opening dialog. It does not have to be shown inside of the application window. Instead let it pop a new window with the OS file open dialog.

### Color Chooser

Implementation of a simple Color Picker widget is not that hard really. Three sliders for RGB and a box to show the color chosen.
You can also use the OS (Windows) specific color picker. And skip the implementation inside you app altogether.